# Need help in the continuity question

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

could someone please explain to me the following question:

Let $f,g$ be continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $f(r) = g(r)$ for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. Is it true that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

My claim is that it should be true since $f$ and $g$ are continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so if $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then it cant be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

So, is my claim correct and if it is how am I supposed to prove it (please give me some hints)
Also, if my claim is wrong, could you please explain to me as to why its wrong`

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You might want to use the following facts:

1. $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for every sequence $x_n \to x$ we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.
2. for every $x\in \mathbb R$ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq \mathbb Q$ such that $x_n \to x$.

Comment: Thanks Ludolila, now I understand how to do this question

Comment: You're welcome, good luck! :)

Comment: I am having a little bit of trouble proving this. The sequential criterion says that for a sequences of (x_n) that converges to c, the sequence of f(x_n) converges to f(c).  and by doing the same with g(x), and then concluding that g(c) = f(c) for all c in R
 c is any arbitary number in R

Comment: is that how I am supposed to do it or is there any other way

Comment: Yes, that's the idea! You start with an arbitrary number $c\in  \mathbb R$, then pick a rational sequence $x_n\to c$, then apply the functions + the fact that $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$ for every element of the sequence. Also use the fact that the limit of a sequence is unique, and thus $f(c)=g(c)$...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the functions coincide :). If you wish, you can use the following fact from topology: if $f,g:X\to Y$, where $Y$ is Hausdorff ($X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces of course), are continuous, then the set $\{x\in X| \ f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$. How to apply it here? Note that if $f(q) = g(q)$ for all rational $q$, then the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}| \ f(x) = g(x)\}$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and at the same time must be closed... Hence it coincides with $\mathbb{R}$ (clearly $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff)! ;)

If you don't want to use this fact from topology, you can proceed as follows. Take any $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$. Take any sequence of rational numbers $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n = x$ (such sequence can clearly be chosen). Then according to your condition, $f(q_n) = g(q_n)$ for all $n$. Hence, $f(x) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(q_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} g(q_n) = g(\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n) = g(x)$ (the first and the last equalities are due to continuity of $f$ and $g$...). And you're done.

Comment: Hey C_M, I havent actually studied topology so I don't think I will be able to use your approach. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I am trying to prove it a little differently

Comment: What I am trying to do is to show that | f(x) - g(x) | < Epsilon for all x in R and for all epsilion > o. Would that proof work?

Comment: but you've got to be careful, I mean, at first fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$. You want to show that $f(x) = g(x)$. It'll be true if you show as you've stated that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon >0$. To show this you use continuity of $f$ and $g$ and the fact that they coincide at rational points which can be found in arbitrarily small neighbourhoods of irrational points...

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is some $x$ where $f(x)\neq g(x)$ Let $\epsilon=|f(x)-g(x)|/3$ Apply the definition of continuity-all the values at rational points within $\delta$ nearby can't be that close to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Comment: Ross I dont really understand what you meant in the last part "all rational values nearby cant be close to f and g' ?

Comment: and I am trying to prove it a little differently

Comment: What I am trying to do is to show that | f(x) - g(x) | < Epsilon for all x in R and for all epsilion > o. Would that proof work?

Comment: I reworded it a bit. I am proving $f(x)=g(x)$ by contradiction, if they disagree somewhere either one is discontinuous or they disagree on some rational

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are equal on $\mathbb{R}$.

An easy way to see this is to note that for a continuous function $f$, and a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$, it is the case that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.

For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you can find a sequence of rationals $q_n \rightarrow x$. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and $f(q_n) = g(q_n)$ for each $q_n$, it follows that $f(x) = g(x)$.

---

To prove that if $x_n \rightarrow x$ then $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$;

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta > 0 $ s.t. $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x - y \rvert < \delta$.

Then as $x_n \rightarrow x$, $\exists N$ such that $\lvert x_n - x \rvert < \delta$ whenever $n > N$.

Hence whenever $n > N$ we have $\lvert f(x) - f(x_n) \rvert < \epsilon$, and therefore $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.